# General analysis of logical explosions

Tags: logic, terminology

I've seen the word *explosion* used in basic logic and deontic logic. The commonality seems to be an explosion is when the 'topic' of a logic universally applies, i.e. everything can be inferred or everything is obligatory.

So this "phenomenon" sounds like what is called *collapse* in modal logic, where everything is necessary. In epistemic logic, then, *logical omniscience* would be the explosive situation?

But I suppose there has to be a little bit more to it. "Everything is possible," and, "Everything exists," seem less implausible than, "Everything is necessary." "Everything is permitted, but just barely permitted (not on account of also being obligated, then)," is less objectionable than, "Everything is forbidden" (which on the surface, anyway, sounds even more catastrophic than, "Everything is obligatory" (I say "surface" because **FR***A* can be interchanged with **OB**~*A*)). But what about, "Everything is supererogatory"?

**When is the global application of a logic's topic, an explosive situation in that logic?**

Comment: It doesn't matter what is or is not more "objectionable", it is only the discriminative power that matters for logic. If it cannot discriminate between types of propositions, be they called true/false, necessary/possible, good/bad, or whatever, it is useless as a tool. If that is truly not needed in some area then such logic is not needed there either. A logic has a topic only to the extent that it has no explosions, but read [Kabay's Defense of Trivialism](https://minerva-access.unimelb.edu.au/bitstream/handle/11343/35203/117801_A%20Defense%20of%20Trivialismelectronic.pdf) for amusement.

Comment: Regarding your intuition ""Everything is possible"...seem less implausible than "Everything is necessary"", this sounds logically impossible. Everything certainly includes the proposition "Everything is necessary", so if "Everything is necessary" is impossible, then "Everything is possible" is impossible *a fortiori*. So seems every explosion is of the same type like *strange flowers in space* mentioned in [Shurangama sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html)...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, the implausibility claim I made is part of a confusion I have about the scope of explosions. When they say "everything can be inferred," do they mean every sentence in a purely linguistic way, or do they mean every well-formed formula, or...? Like, does A&~A lead to, "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously"? So likewise, is, "Everything is necessary," such that, "It is possible that everything is necessary," is within the scope of a modal explosion/collapse?

Comment: The scope of explosion applies to any sentence (closed wff) of a formal theory with a non-paraconsistent logic. If your theory somehow proves A&~A, then any sentence B which can be expressed as a sentence such as "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" can be derived (since the theory must also prove A∨B per ∨-introduction rule, and since it also proves ~A, then it must prove B). Similarly, ◊□p is a wff in modal logic for an arbitrary sentence p which itself may recursively contain well-formed modal operators, so explosion (proves ◊□p) or modal collapse (proves □◊□p) also applies...

Comment: We can use ~◊□p (□◊~p) to express the implausibility of your above intuition "Everything is necessary" is impossible when p is an arbitrary sentence, then certainly □p is still a sentence by definition which belongs to the set {Everything}. So it's exactly at the same modal level of the implausibility of your "Everything is possible" claim which can be expressed as ~◊◊q (□□~q) where q is an arbitrary sentence. Thus it's clear actually necessarily the implausibility of "Everything is possible" sounds more implausible than that of "Everything is necessary" per axiom D □p→◊p, if not same level...

Comment: Thank you so much! Side-note: I wonder how we might apply this to Hannah Arendt's criticism of, "Everything is possible," in politics. Given her characterization of the metaphysics that go into some totalitarian structures, I suspect she was referring to a case of, "Everything is possible," that is metaphysically unrestricted. And then per your analysis, we find that not everything is possible, wherefore... IOW I used to accept the bulk of Arendt's theory of totalitarianism but didn't understand this specific aspect of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps best to start with the concept of a theory, where 'theory' is understood in its most general sense as a set of sentences, usually closed under the relation of logical consequence, and 'sentence' is a well-formed formula with no free variables. A theory explodes if every sentence of the language is a theorem. Such a theory is useless, since it does not provide any way to distinguish what holds from what does not hold. If your logic includes the principle of explosion, as classical logic and many other logics do, then any contradiction within a theory leads to explosion. If your logic does not include the principle of explosion, which is to say that it is paraconsistent, then a theory may be able to accommodate a contradiction without explosion.

To say of a logic itself that it experiences explosion would be to say that the logic allows all sentences to be proved as theorems. Again, such a logic would be useless.

Modal collapse is a weaker condition than explosion. A modal theory collapses if "P ↔ □P" and "P ↔ ◇P" hold for any P. The whole point of an alethic modal theory is to distinguish between something being contingently true and being necessarily or possibly true, so if those biconditionals hold, the distinction becomes impossible.

Logical omniscience is weaker still and does not imply any kind of collapse. A logically omniscient agent knows all logical truths, so we would have the rule:

```
 ⊢ P
 ---
 KP
```

In deontic logic, if we attempt to express conditional obligations as material implications, we run into [Chisholm's contrary-to-duty paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/#CondObliChisPuzz), and depending on how the logic of obligation is set up, we could get either an inconsistency or a modal collapse leading to everything being obligatory.

Hughes and Cresswell (A New Introduction to Modal Logic, 1996) distinguish the following three modal systems.

1. Triv.  This is the trivial modal logic that results from system D together with the axiom P → □P. This logic is consistent and corresponds to the frame consisting of a single world that is accessible to itself. Note that we need D and not just K, since D provides us with the axiom  □P → ◇P.
2. Ver.  This results from taking system K together with the axiom □P. Although this is really strange, since it includes as a theorem □⊥, it is consistent. It corresponds to the frame consisting of a single world that is not accessible to itself.
3. ℒ.  This is the inconsistent system and includes all sentences as theorems.

Hughes and Cresswell don't seem to consider modal systems with ◇P as an axiom, but bear in mind that these would include ◇⊥ as a theorem, which would require a non-normal modal logic.

Comment: I thought I had accepted this answer longer ago. Something must be going (even more) wrong with my mind :/